# Is there a way to create a CMYK Format Canvas without using RenderTargetBitmap first?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image-processing, rendering

**TL;DR mode:**
Is there a way to get a BitmapSource from a DrawingVisual without using RenderTargetBitmap, whilst still having the 'crop' utility a RenderTargetBitmap affords you.

**Full Question:**
My issue is an awkward one, I'm using a number of image editing processes to effectively crop, resize, rotate and perform all that usual stuff expected of even basic image editing in an automated manner, and everything is working just fine except for one incredibly annoying caveat: Images profiled as CMYK can't be processed then saved again as CMYK without doing a little dance with RenderTargetBitmap *(which breaks and refuses to create an instance of itself with any PixelFormat other than "PixelFormats.Default" or "PixelFormats.Pbgra32")* and the FormatConvertedBitmap class to even get the image to go back to being a CMYK

So where you might think, *'oh this is easy, just...'*

```
var newCanvas = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                width, height, // Dimensions
                96, 96,        // DPI
                PixelFormats.Cmyk32); // <---- Like so
```

The class just breaks and gives the error:
***System.ArgumentException: ''Cmyk32' PixelFormat is not supported for this operation. Arg_ParamName_Name'***

So instead I'm having to do a little trick with the full-code involved being as such:

```
string myUri = ""    // Some CMYK Image
int newWidth = 600;  // Just for this example, real values come in elsewhere
int newHeight = 400; // As above

// Load the image
BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(FullURL), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
 
//Define the new size
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)                 // Set new size of img.
DrawingGroup group = new DrawingGroup();                        // Create a group for img layers
group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(image, decoder.Frames[0])); // Add loaded image
// (sometimes more children will be added, so it must be a DrawingGroup)
 
// Prepare the group to be rendered.
var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var drawing = drawingVisual.RenderOpen()) {
     // Additional things such as shapes may be added here later
     drawing.DrawDrawing(group);
     }

// Create what is effectively the canvas the image goes into
var resizedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(
     newWidth, newHeight,
     96, 96,     
     PixelFormats.Default); // <---- I'm forced to do this
     
// And then render it 
resizedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

// THEN after that, convert it back too CMYK32
var fcb = new FormatConvertedBitmap(resizedImage, PixelFormats.Cmyk32, null, 0);
```

This "**FormatConvertedBitmap** fcb" is then saved as a TIFF, and a CMYK TIFF at that. Success, right?

Well no, during this little dance between "PixelFormats.Default" and "PixelFormats.Cmyk32" done with RenderTargetBitmap -> FormatConvertedBitmap, it seems the Default conversion is enough to upset all of the colours inside the file, not a lot, but enough that it's no longer the true image that was input at the start.

For example, what might have been a block of **CMYK(0,0,0,100)** pixels, so pure jet-black, might now be **CMYK(2,3,2,96)**. So it's dropped the blac(K) down 4%, and pushed the (C)yan, (M)agenta, and (Y)ellow up 2-3%, creating a foggier image that looks washed-out.

My working theory, although i have no way yet of proving it 100% true, is that this problem is being caused by the RenderTargetBitmap effectively making it an RGB image first.

Is there any way at all to truly preserve CMYK images whilst editing them in the layered and 'croppable' way I showed, or some way to effectively save the image without needing to use RenderTargetBitmap? It seems insane that Microsoft even has this class that has the option to set PixelFormat, except the only format that works is what amounts to "Default". Why even give the option in the function? (I realize I'm ranting now).

Does anyone know of a way to solve this weird issue?

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly, but are you asking how to get a BitmapSource from a DrawingVisual without using RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: In essence, yes, with a colour profile that is either manually set to CMYK, or can understand that its original format was CMYK and so it should have that when saved.

... I might add this at the start as a TL;DR summary.

Comment: I should also mention that i need the "crop" functionality a RenderTargetBitmap affords me, as in you can tell the RenderTargetBitmap to be, lets say, 200x200px, and then stuff a 400x400px image inside it, and on render, it will have cropped it to 200x200px.

Comment: I think this can not be done without RenderTargetBitmap. You may however do the format conversion from Pbgra32 to Cmyk32 yourself.

Comment: That's unfortunate if true, it adds a huge amount of complexity to an issue created solely by one line of code.

Comment: Without having tried anything, I would guess that the color modification already happens during rendering into the RenderTargetBitmap. Have you checked that?

Comment: I don't really have any way of testing that, that I'm aware of. Simply saving the RenderTargetBitmap itself and avoiding the conversion back to CMYK creates an RGB image with even more drastically wrong colours when looked at in software like Photoshop.